# Permission issue when installing with nginx

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, nginx, permissions, file-permissions

I have installed different Magento sites using nginx. I have 5 sites, 4 of them use php7.1 and there's one that uses php7.0.

I have created two different sites-availaible:

[image]

And both of them have sites as these one: (the other magento2.1 uses php7.0 and I comment and uncomment because I still haven't discovered how to use both at the same time -> fastcgi_backend gives error if both are working at the same time)

[image]

Now the issue comes when, once all Magento files added, installed and nginx properly set up it gives me an permissions error:

```
2019/03/15 11:20:31 [error] 3266#3266: *19 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/parera_dev.com/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/.
Class Magento\Directory\Helper\Data\Proxy generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. in /var/www/html/parera_dev.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/parera_dev.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Directo...')
#1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Directo...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Directo...')
#" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: parera.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "www.parera.com"
```

The permissions I set up where these:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;    
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R raul:www-data .;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento;
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service;
```

With these permissions, my other 7.1 sites work, well, 1 of 4 work, the other 3 give me this exact error.

Exceptionally I added this command to try and fix it but no luck:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

I compile and deploy after but no change.

I share the nginx conf because it might be some kind of nginx conf error.

Thank you

Comment: your php-fpm user must be `raul` or `www-data`  and dont run commands as `root`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error on local environment.

The error was due to an **nginx** permissions error.

Running this on macOS with local brew services nginx.

**Local dev env**

- macOS
- brew services *nginx, php7.2*
- Magento 2.3.4

Error in the `/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log` file was

```
 [crit] 7566#0: *31067 open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000035" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1,
```

**Solution for this error**

Change the owner for the folders under `/usr/local/var/run/nginx/`

For instance, I fixed it with

```
sudo chown myloginuser:admin -R /usr/local/var/run/nginx
```

Now I can upload product images. So maybe try this if you encounter this issue.